# Can assign Array<Object> to an Array of any class

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow doesn't find any type errors with the below:

```
const a : Array<Object> = [{x:2}, {y:"hi"}];
const b : Array<SomeClass> = a;
```

SomeClass can be either a class or type alias.

Is there a setting I need to enable to catch this error or is it expected?

Answer (score 4):

[`Object`](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#the-object-type) in Flow is equivalent to [`any`](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#any) but limited to object types (primitives and arrays (as of Flow 0.30) are not inhabitants of the set of `Object`).  Quoting from [the docs on `any`](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#any):

> `any` is simultaneously a supertype of all types and a subtype of all types. Intuitively, an any value can take the place of “any” other value, and Flow will understand that to be well-typed.

Since `Object` is like `any`, when we tell Flow that `a` is an `Array<Object>` we are telling it "`a` is an array containing the correct type ... whatever that is".  Because `Object` is a subtype of `SomeClass` (see above, regarding `any`) it is assignable to an `Array<SomeClass>`.

The fix is to mark `a` as either [`mixed`](https://flowtype.org/docs/builtins.html#mixed) or as the type it is (even if that type is a union type):

```
type SomeType = {x: number} | {y: string}
const a: Array<SomeType> = [{x:2}, {y:"hi"}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation!

Comment: Just a thought - it's slightly confusing when compared to other OOP languages though. Perhaps it should have been named `AnyObject`,  while `Object` would instead just be a super type of all non-primitive types.